# MySQL query keeps failing. page is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redirect

I have this simple insert query that basically add one row to the db table. but it is not only adding the row but its not redirecting neither. i tried redirecting through javaScript, it gets redirected but still not adding the row. the page is live at: 
http://arj-profile.com/public/new_subject.php
(when you go the link click on about widget and then click on add a subject.

i was originally trying this on mamp and i have tried turning on output buffering on php.ini too, still no luck.

any help appreciated. if you need additional information just console log on the above link or let me know i can provide it my entire tables and db as well.

the form page has the following code:

```
<!-- including functions -->
<?php include("../includes/db_connect.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<!-- query -->

<!-- end of query -->
<!-- including header -->
<?php include("../includes/header.php") ?>
<?php find_selected_page();?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<!-- menu -->
      <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
        <?php echo navigation(); ?>
      </div>
<!-- body -->
      <div class="col-md-9 body">

        <form action="create_subject.php" method="post">
            <p>Subject name: 
                <input type="text" name="menu_name" value=""/>
            <p>
            <p>Position
                <select name="position">
                <?php 
                $subject_set = find_all_subjects();
                $subject_count = mysqli_num_rows ($subject_set);
                for ($count = 1; $count <= ($subject_count + 1); $count++){
                        echo "<option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";
                        } 
                ?>

                </select>
            </p>
            <p>Visible: 
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" />No
                &nbsp
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" />Yes
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>
            <br />
            <!-- redirect -->
            <a href="manage-content.php">Cancel</a>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<?php include("../includes/footer.php") ?>
```

please try adding but filling out the form, as you see it goes to the following page which actually contains the query but it is not supposed to go there, it should just redirect back to the create_subject.php.

```
<?php include("../includes/db_connect.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $menu_name = mysqli_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
        $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
        $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

        $menu_name = mysqli_prep($menu_name); 

        $query = "insert into subjects("; 
        $query = " menu_name, position, visible";
        $query = ") values (";
        $query = " '{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible}";
        $query = ")"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
        if ($result){
            $msg = "Subject created"; 
            redirect_to("manage_subject.php");
        } 
    }else {
        $msg = "Subject creation failed";
        redirect_to("new_subject.php");

    }
?>


<?php
    if (isset($connection)){mysqli_close($connection); }
?>
```

**in my function.php i have:**

```
<?php

function redirect_to($new_location){
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
    exit;
}
function mysqli_prep($string){
    global $connection;
    $escape_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($cnnection, $string); 
    return $escape_string; 
}

function confirm_query($result_set){
    if (!$result_set){
        die("DB Query Failed");
    }
}

function find_all_subjects(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "select * ";
    $query .= "from subjects ";
    $query .= "where visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "order by position asc";
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    return $subject_set;
}

function find_pages_for_subjects($subject_id){
        global $connection; 
        $safe_subject_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);
        $query = "select * ";
        $query .= "from pages ";
        $query .= "where visible = 1 ";
        // an aditional line to relate pages to the subject, subject_id is what rlate two tables together
        // dont forget space between lines
        $query .= "AND subject_id = {$safe_subject_id} ";
        $query .= "order by position asc";
        $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        // the result captured can not be used twice for two different queries 
        // so result varibale should have unique names 
        confirm_query($page_set);
        return $page_set;
}

function find_subject_by_id($subject_id){
    global $connection;
    $safe_subject_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id); 
    $query = "select * ";
    $query .= "from subjects ";
    $query .= "where id = {$safe_subject_id} ";
    $query .= "limit 1";

    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    if ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)){

        return $subject;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}


function find_page_by_id($page_id){
    global $connection;
    $safe_page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $page_id); 
    $query = "select * ";
    $query .= "from pages ";
    $query .= "where id = {$safe_page_id} ";
    $query .= "limit 1";

    $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($page_set);
    if ($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){

        return $page;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
function find_selected_page(){
    global $current_subject; 
    global $current_page;  
    if (isset($_GET["subject"])){

        $current_subject = find_subject_by_id($_GET["subject"]);
        $current_page = null; 

    } elseif (isset($_GET["page"])){

        $current_page = find_page_by_id($_GET["page"]);
        $current_subject = null;  

    } else{

        $current_subject = null;  
        $current_page = null; 

    }

}

function navigation(){

    $output = "<ul>";
            $subject_set = find_all_subjects(); 
            while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)){ 

                $output .= "<li><a href=\"manage-content.php?subject="; 
                $output .= urlencode($subject["id"]);
                $output .= "\">";
                $output .= $subject["menu_name"];
                $output .= "</a>";
                $page_set = find_pages_for_subjects($subject["id"]);
                $output .= "<ul>";  
                    while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){ 
                        $output .= "<li><a href=\"manage-content.php?page=";
                        $output .= urlencode($page["id"]);
                        $output .= "\">";
                        $output .= $page["menu_name"];
                        $output .= "</a></li>";     
                    } 
                    mysqli_free_result($page_set);
                    $output .= "</ul></li>";
            } 
            mysqli_free_result($subject_set);
            $output .= "</ul>";
            return $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: you have a typo in your `mysqli_prep` function - the line `mysqli_real_escape_string($cnnection, $string);` contains an incorrectly spelled `$cnnection`

Comment: thanks i fixed that, but still its not getting added to the row and the page is not redirecting.

Comment: You must use java-script for redirection in this case and use it after adding the records in database.

Comment: Use it:         if ($result){
            $msg = "Subject created"; 
           ?>window.location.href='test.php'<?php
        }

Comment: are opening a <?php in the end?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
        if ($result){
            $msg = "Subject created"; 
            if ($result){ $msg = "Subject created"; ?>window.location.href='manage_subject.php'<?php }
        }

Comment: Yes we have to close first PHP and then write javascript code and then again open the PHP tag.

Comment: Yes now try with this

Comment: updated on the link, still gets redirected to the create_subject.php. i am sorry maybe i am making mistake but you could try

Comment: and its not added neither

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Could you please put alert in that section so that we can check is it working or not. Like: alert('I am here'); just before window.location.href='manage_subject.php

Comment: What do you get if you were to add `exit( print_r( $_POST ) );` in `create_subject.php`  just before you execute the insert query? Does the script reach that point, does it show the print out of the POST array?

Comment: i add the what Raghbendra Nayak said and got nothing, i added what RamRaider said i got this: Array ( [menu_name] => 1312312 [position] => 3 [visible] => 1 [submit] => Submit ) 1

Comment: updated on the link as well

Comment: Why you are not using single line insert query in create_subject.php page like: $sql = "INSERT INTO subjects(menu_name, position, visible)
VALUES ('John', 'john@example.com','los angeles')";

Comment: ok - so it reaches as far as the sql query - how does the final sql query look if you were to echo that? Try running that in your mysql gui or from the commandline

Comment: Yes I have checked and can see the printed array that means some went wrong in php script

Comment: Yes I do agree with @RamRaider

Comment: Bingo! it got added to the table but still some problem with redirect can you see?

Comment: Ok let me: you have added: window.location.href='create_subject.php'

Comment: don't use javascript for the redirect, use php ~ `header('location:page.php')` etc and also remove the commented database details from the source code

Comment: Could you show me peace of code for redirection what you have written? because its showing you added create_subject.php so its redirecting on same page

Comment: HAHA guys the added stuff haha, the code for redirecting is this: if ($result){ header("Location: " . "arj-profile.com/public/new_subject.php"); exit; }

Comment: So all working fine now ..?

Comment: uugh is just not redirecting when i click submit. you see?

Comment: if ($result){ header("Location: " . "http://arj-profile.com/public/manage-content.php?subject=1"); exit; }

Comment: Yes I have checked could you try with javascript?

Comment: it just keeps going to the action of the form which is create_subject.php.

Comment: if ($result){ $msg = "Subject created"; ?>window.location.href='www.google.com'<?php } }

Comment: print the result before if condition and check I think there is some problem

Comment: It doesn't matter, form action means form will submit on that action and if we add redirection to any other page then that will redirect. could you show me at which page you want to redirect it .??? and code of that page.

Comment: honestly i dont care which page it goes to. i just want the redirect to work. i have this right now. i added the print too . $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
   exit( print_r( $_POST ) );
   if ($result){ $msg = "Subject created"; ?>window.location.href='www.google.com'<?php } }
 }else {
  $msg = "Subject creation failed";
  redirect_to("new_subject.php");

Comment: May be your target page have some code which is not proper, so for testing you can try it for any new page, just create test page and say thnaks only at that page and try to redirect at that page

Comment: i created test.php as well but now i am getting in create_subject again this time i am getting: window.location.href = "test.php";

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS, i figure out the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mysqli_prep( $string ){
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $string );  
}



<?php include("../includes/db_connect.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php

    $redir='new_subject.php';

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

        $menu_name = mysqli_prep( $_POST["menu_name"] );
        $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
        $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

        $query = "insert into subjects 
            ( menu_name, position, visible ) 
            values 
            ( '{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible} )"; 



        $result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );
        if ( $connection ) mysqli_close( $connection );

        if( $result ) $redir='manage_subject.php';
    }

    redirect_to( $redir );
?>
```